# mkdir error, permission denied

Tags: linux, kali-linux, mkdir, snap

i was installed spotify yesterday with snap in kali linux, then i run with snap run spotify and i get error like this :

```
snap run spotify
WARNING: cgroup v2 is not fully supported yet, proceeding with partial confinement
mkdir: cannot create directory '/run/user/0': Permission denied
No protocol specified
No protocol specified
Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused

(spotify:9119): Gtk-WARNING **: 00:22:57.815: cannot open display: :0.0
```

can you help me fix this please, i just learn in this operating system

Comment: AFAIK: Kali is a sort of a specialized tool, not a general purpose operating system. So if you're looking to learn (and to run Spotify, and not pentesting tools), you might want to use a distribution more suited for that. (Maybe Ubuntu or Fedora, even Arch is more general purpose.)

Comment: Also, at a guess, it looks like you are running it as root when it doesn't want to be run as root.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but I was running in root (ran sudo su first). If you don't run spotify in root kali will add spotify to a key ring and should start. If the app doesn't run right away just close it and run spotify again.